# Every new day I have this error : failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, log, laravel

I have this error

```
The stream or file "/data/www/site.com/storage/logs/laravel-2021-01-14.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root       30833 Jan 14 09:00 laravel-2021-01-14.log
```

When I change the directory permission it works BUT after one day I got the same error !

Comment: Could you please specify in your post what exactly your question is? Using Laravel? Making some change persist after reboot? Changing permissions? I suppose it involves resolving the error you mention, but without a clear question, it's difficult to give a clear answer. Adding a bit more context would be nice too, such as when/how is the error triggered, by what (Laravel probably, but through which use), in which environment, etc...

Comment: Perhaps [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel/37266353#37266353)?